# quarter car model matlab code ode45 plotting

Tags: matlab, plot, input, ode, ode45

I have a quarter car model which is a 2-dof system with damper and spring
with following codes with a diagram;

[image: quarter car model]

```
function dx = ode_2dof(t,x)
m1=500;
c1=1200;
k1=25000;
k2=15000;
m2=50;
dx=zeros(4,1);
dx(1)=x(2)
dx(2)=-(c1/m1)*(x(2)-x(4))-(k1/m1)*(x(1)-x(3))
dx(3)=x(4)
dx(4)=(c1/m2)*(x(2)-x(4))+(k1/m2)*(x(1)-x(3))-k2*x(3)
end
```

Here, i tried to put an input as a condition of the road. First, i set the step input as a height of 0.01 metre after 0.5 second so i changed the function dx(4) as changing the function file as following;

```
dx(4)=(c1/m2)*(x(2)-x(4))+(k1/m2)*(x(1)-x(3))-k2*(x(3)-y)
```

with adding;

```
if y>0.5
y=0.01
elseif
y=0
```

between the code dx=zeros(4,1) and dx(1)=x(2).

recalling this function, I could plot the graphs for x1 and x2 (i.e car and tire) displacements as following codes;

```
[t x] = ode45(@ode_2dof,[0 3],[0.7 0 0.35 0]) %initial position of the car and the tyre
x1_position=x(:,1);
x2_position=x(:,3);
figure
plot(t,x1_position,t,x2_position);
grid on
legend('x1 position','x2 position');
```

Question 1, i've got a graph as

[image: graph 1]

but this is not the graph I want, how can I get the graph with x1 settling at 0.7 and x2 at 0.35 respectively as the initial condition, not at 0?

Also, I tried to change the x1, k1 and k2 values to see how it affects on the displacements with changing the x1, k1 and k2 values respectively in the function file and saved separately.

```
function dx = ode_2dof2700(t,x)
c1=2700

function dx = ode_2dof40000(t,x)
k1=40000

function dx = ode_2dof30000(t,x)
k2=30000

function dx = ode_2dofmix(t,x)
c1=2700
k1=40000
k2=30000
```

Question 2, i tried to plot the graph all x1 and x2 at the same time in different graphs as following;

```
[t x] = ode45(@ode_2dof,[0 5],[0.7 0 0.35 0])
x1_position=x(:,1);
x2_position=x(:,3);
[t x] = ode45(@ode_2dof2700,[0 5],[0.7 0 0.35 0])
x1_position_2700=x(:,1);
x2_position_2700=x(:,3);
[t x] = ode45(@ode_2dof40000,[0 5],[0.7 0 0.35 0])
x1_position_40000=x(:,1);
x2_position_40000=x(:,3);
[t x] = ode45(@ode_2dof30000,[0 5],[0.7 0 0.35 0])
x1_position_30000=x(:,1);
x2_position_30000=x(:,3);
[t x] = ode45(@ode_2dofmix,[0 5],[0.7 0 0.35 0])
x1_position_mix=x(:,1);
x2_position_mix=x(:,3);

figure
plot(t,x1_position,t,x1_position_2700,t,x1_position_40000,t,x1_position_30000,t,x1_position_mix);
grid on
```

but i've got an error that the vector array have to be matched. It is actually different as x1_position is 1361x1 and x2_position_2700 is 1041x1 etc. how can i change the code to match the array?

Question 3, if i want to set a sinusoidal input with an amplitude of 0.01 metre, how should i change the input?

Thanks

Comment: About question2: you have to save each `t` with your `x1` & `x2` to match every [t,x1] pairs.Then you could plot them at a same time by calling something like `plot(t,x1_position,t_2700,x1_position_2700,t_40000,x1_position_40000,t_30000,x1_position_30000,t_mix,x1_position_mix);`

Comment: i don't understand that i have to save each t with x1 and x2. I tried to saved the ode files of the each different values and recalling with plot function and i got an error as what i got before. could you tell me more specifically?

Comment: Sorry, my English is quite weak. I mean `[t1 x1] = ode45(...)` , `[t2 x2] = ode45(...)`; then you could plot them by `plot(t1,x1(:,1),t2,x2(:,1))`. Just match every `t` and `x` in your `plot`.

Comment: Now its working! thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a minor mistake in your equations, you should divide by m everything like here

```
dudt(1) = u(2);
dudt(2) = -(c2/m2)*(u(2)-u(4))-(k2/m2)*(u(1)-u(3))-9.8;
dudt(3) = u(4);
dudt(4) = -(k1/m1)*(u(3)-y)+(k2/m1)*(u(1)-u(3))-(c1/m1)*(u(4)-yl)+(c2/m1)*(u(2)-u(4))-9.8;
```

this includes damping in both dofs, for future fellas looking at the same problem get things right!